# My question was put on hold as too broad - why?

Tags: discussion

My [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/57764/raspberry-pi-zero-otg-ssh-alternative-to-bonjour-itunes-quicktime-windows) was put on hold as too broad.  My question is about getting ssh working from windows to the Raspberry pi zero without installing bonjour etc; - Why is that too broad?  I can't get much more specific without knowing the answer!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48713/discussion-on-question-by-menasheh-my-question-was-put-on-hold-as-too-broad-wh).